# How can the commutator of vector fields be a genuine vector field?

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds, vector-fields, lie-derivative

I want to look at the transformation law for the commutator of two basis vectors. I understand completely how this works for a holonomic frame: The basis vector fields act on functions as the partial derivative operators wrt to the appropriate coordinates, so the commutator vanishes. But when we transform to an anholonomic frame, the basis vector (fields) aren’t going to be the partial derivatives for some coordinate system, so the resulting components will be nonvanishing.

This transformation law seems to me to reek of inhomogeneity, and I can’t seem to reconcile it with what I’ve been taught, which is that the commutator of vector fields is itself a vector field.

UPDATE: [image]

Here’s my problem. The object I have here should be a tensor (right?), and it vanishes in the holonomic frame. But now, in the anholonomic frame, I get nonzero terms. This should not be how a tensor transforms. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Well, you have an explicit formula that, in particular, gives you that vector field you get when you take the commutator of arbitrary vector fields (just because the frame is holonomic doesn't mean that the commutator of general vector fields will be $0$). If you have taken a course in smooth manifolds, you know that linearity over $C^\infty$ functions establishes that you have a tensor field, and that is the case with the bracket of two vector fields.

Comment: Thanks for your edit (although we'd prefer such equations to be [typeset](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)), which proves $e_a=\Lambda_a^\mu\partial_\mu,\,e_b=\Lambda_b^\nu\partial_\nu\implies[e_a,\,e_b]=(e_a\Lambda_b^\mu-e_n\Lambda_a^\mu)\partial_\mu$. This computes the commutator of two *components* of the same tensor. My calculations were of the commutator of two true vectors, not individual components.

Comment: @J.G. I think you meant ‘b’ instead of ‘n’ for the index on the last e... And I still don’t get why my object goes from being zero to the expression I got below if it is truly a vector.

Comment: Sorry, yes, I did. What I'm saying is if the quantities whose commutator you compute have uncontracted indices, the remainder will have twice as many, so won't transform the same way. (My original answer worked without uncontracted indices; the current version is different in that the way it defines a commutator automatically adds a contraction.)

Comment: @J.G. I think I’m starting to understand... But how does the method in your answer work if the basis used is not a coordinate basis?

Comment: @excitonfield If we define vectors by how they transform under a change in coordinates, a proof that something is a vector requires two coordinate systems. If you define them another way you can specify, the same requirements will apply to a proof the two definitions are equivalent, but we can put that aside for now & discuss how an alternative definition lets us not only define the two-vectors Lie derivative, but also prove it transforms as a vector.

Comment: @J.G. Okay, let's put it this way. If I were to take $ {\displaystyle [X,Y]=\left(X^{j}\partial _{j}Y^{i}-Y^{j}\partial _{j}X^{i}\right)\partial _{i}.} $ and turn all the $\partial _{j}$ into $e_{j}$, would the resulting formula $ {\displaystyle [X,Y]=\left(X^{j}e_{j}Y^{i}-Y^{j}e_{j}X^{i}\right)e_{i}} $ still be valid?

Comment: @excitonfield Only if you suitably redefined the commutator in the second formula, otherwise we'd have$$(X^j\partial_jY^i-Y^j\partial_jX^i)\partial_i=(X^je_jY^i-Y^je_jX^i)e_i.$$Only the LHS is a differential operator.

Comment: @J.G. I think I figured this whole thing out!! I learned about the ‘commutator coefficients’, which are the symbols I derived above. I can see now how we shouldn’t expect my example to transform like a tensor, and how the commutator coefficients actually go on to correct the torsion tensor components in anholonomic frames to make sure they transform properly like tensors.

Comment: @J.G. And furthermore, I was able to go through and verify that the whole object is at least still a vector because the inhomogeneous additive term I was talking about is also a vector. I realized how even though it transforms funny as a result of the basis vector indices, just like you were mentioning, it is still a vector. Thanks so much for the patience and help!!

Answer (score 3):

Since vectors transforms as $V^a=x^a_AV^A$ between two coordinate systems with $x^a_A:=\frac{\partial x^a}{\partial x^A}$,$$\begin{align}U^a\partial_aV^b&=U^Ax^a_A\partial_a(x^b_BV^B)\\&=U^A\partial_A(x^b_BV^B)\\&=U^A\partial_AV^Bx^b_B+U^AV^B\underbrace{x^b_{AB}}_{\tfrac{\partial^2x^a}{\partial x^A\partial x^B}},\end{align}$$so $U^a\partial_aV^b-V^a\partial_aU^b=x^b_B(U^A\partial_AV^B-V^A\partial_AU^B)$, i.e. $£_UV^b=x^b_B£_UV^B$. This is the usual transformation law for a vector.

Comment: @excitonfield Perhaps you instead wanted a proof the Lie derivative transforms as a vector. (Two commutator definitions are common.) I'll let you know when I've updated my answer.

Comment: @excitonfield OK, done.

Comment: I just don’t understand how this reconciles with the whole inhomogeneity issue I had... I don’t understand how we can expect the commutator in my initial question to be well-defined if it vanishes in one frame, but not in another...

Comment: @excitonfield I think you need to update your question to show a putative example of a vector that's $0$ in one frame but not another because, as I've shown, the Lie derivative transforms tensorally.

Comment: Just put one in :)